# add into selectlist an item only if it doesn't exist into razor

Tags: razor, contains, selectlist

I want to create selectlist dynamically by traversing child nodes with 'language' property. So, want to add this property value as a select list item only if it is not added previously.

I have following code.

```
@{


       var litem = new List<SelectListItem>();

       litem.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "All", Value = "" });

       foreach (var i in Model.Content.Children.Where("Visible"))
          {
             //if (i.GetProperty("language").Value != "")
             if (i.GetProperty("language").Value != "")
             {
              string langstr = i.GetProperty("language").Value.ToString();
              SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = langstr, Value = langstr };

              if ((!(litem.Contains(item))))
               {
                  litem.Add(item);
               }
             }
          }

                    var slang=new SelectList(litem);

                    @Html.DropDownList("drpLang", @slang,  new { @class = "dropdown"})

}
```

But it is not able to check the same item present in list. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, problem that litem contain duplicate,
this because you create new instance of object item and than check is list contain new instance (you not check for same property, you check for exactly same object).

change this line:

```
if ((!(litem.Contains(item))))
```

for something like this:

```
if (litem.All(i => i.Value != item.Value))
```

or if you need unique pair:

```
if (litem.All(i => i.Value != item.Value && i.Text!= item.Text))
```

also recommend move all login in controller and use viewbag for DropDownList

Comment: thanks.... I was using contains. But wht it doesnot work with contains()?

Comment: because contain look for same object, and you create all time new object (with other hash), contain will work only if you get object from list fro example var item = litem.firstordefault(i = i.Value = 'some value')
if you use 'new' key word for item, it's not work because it other object with other hash code